# combine multiple rows in a single field

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have this table:

Number----------user----------value

1---------------A-------------25

1---------------B------------ 28

2---------------C-------------30

2---------------D-------------35

This is what I want:

Number----------user----------value

1---------------A,B-----------25,28

2---------------C,D-----------30,35

There are thousands of records and I am organizing them. What should the sql be?

Comment: Please read the FAQs on how to ask a question. This does not meet any of the requirements set out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Oracle 11g+, then you can use the [`LISTAGG()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions089.htm) function:

```
select "Number",
  listagg("user", ', ') within group (order by "user") "user",
  listagg("value", ', ') within group (order by "user") value
from yourtable
group by "Number"
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd3e5/12)

Comment: For some tables it says “ORA-01489:result of string concatenation is too long”. I dont have privileges to create functions or type. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a search in the site... for *string agresgation* OR *listagg* etc...

in the meantime look [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)